# xfce-panel display list of windows of a single application?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 using xfce 4.12

I use a lot of terminals ( 6-8 ) when working. Is it possible to have a xfce panel that lists all windows of a specific application ( terminal in this case ). I have attached a sample screenshot.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHnsd.png

Can I do this with some other application if it is not possible with xfce-panel?

Why do I need this? Easier to view what terminals are available and can easily click and work in it right away.

Thank you.

Edit: Updated the image to show the panel I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the xfce4-terminal, as well as the xfce panel with the openbox window manager on a Ubuntu 14.04 kernel (3.13.53 linux kernel version), and had a similar problem.

I used the default option on the xfce panel initially which displayed the top panel and the second xfce panel as a dock on the bottom. As a work around I deleted the second panel (the dock), and re-added the second panel at the bottom and elongated its dimensions to have identical dimensions as the the top panel.

The xfce panel has settings which you can adjust by right clicking the panel, selecting panel, and selecting panel-preferences. With in panel-preferences you can delete and add panels as well as change each panels settings. This may be the option you are looking for. Another alternative which I employed, which is a work around all by itself and is to install and configure cairo-dock.

Using cairo-dock you can configure it to show each individual occurrence by selecting the integrated option under the behavior setting.
By doing so the dock will show each individual initialized terminal resting on the dock as shown below.

[image]

Best of luck and go UBUNTU!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry Rivi, I just read re-post, you might ordersorting:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not exactly what I was looking for. I have edited the image to show the panel of interest:  http://i.imgur.com/n1MvLp8.png which is in red. So a dock/panel that shows all windows of a single application i.e. terminal even though other applications like spotify and chrome are open ( please look at top panel )